# List all files changed by a particular user in Github in a specific time interval on multiple branches

Tags: git, github

I need to maintain a Excel for reporting of GitHub repository.

I need list of all file changes of every user on monthly bases.

Is there a provision to track changes of file filter by author of all branches based on time interval defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For listing of file name need to include --name-only

git log --name-only --since=11.08.2014 --until=11.08.2015 --author="developerName"

Answer (score 1):

You can use git log command with different options :

```
git log --since=11.08.2014 --until=11.08.2015 --author="developerName"
```

For different branches, you can execute the command on each branch, after checking out to it.